# Memory leak in between Jersey @BeanParam and HK2 ServiceLocatorImpl

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

We've been running jersey in production for a while now and noticed recently that we started leaking memory. When digging we discovered that starting in HK2 2.3.0 there was a injecteeToResolverCache added to the HK2 class (org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.class)

Here's the line from the ServiceLocatorImpl.class

```
private final Cache<Injectee, InjectionResolver<?>> injecteeToResolverCache = new Cache<Injectee, InjectionResolver<?>>(new Computable<Injectee, InjectionResolver<?>>()
```

In our setup we're using jersey 2.9 (hk 2.3.0) and we have resource methods that use @BeanParam that look something like this :

```
public CustomResponse getStuff(
        @BeanParam Paging paging, @BeanParam CustFilter filter){...
```

What seems to be happening is that HK2 2.3.0 is caching each instance of anything marked as a BeanParameter as an Injectee in the injecteeToResolverCache. Since new instances of "paging" and "filter" BeanParams are created on every call to the "getStuff" resource there are 2 new entries added to the cache on every call. We wound up with over 10 million entries in this cache before things started falling apart.

Has anyone else run into this or are we using the framework incorrectly ?

For now we've downgraded to jersey 2.8 and that seems to be working since it depends on 2.2.0 of Hk2 which doesn't have the injectee cache.

Thanks!
Kris

Comment: I would suggest adding a Jira entry here https://java.net/jira/browse/HK2.  A simple use-case reproducer would be nice, but is not required I guess...

Comment: Also, can we see some of the code for your InjectionResolver?  Thanks

Comment: I filed a bug on Jersey's JIRA (https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2555) but adding one on HK2 makes sense. I'll do that too. We don't have any custom Injection Resolver code. All we do is use the new @BeanParam annotation and let the framework do the rest.

Comment: Added ticket to HK2 https://java.net/jira/browse/HK2-216

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have found the likely cause of the memory leak, but it will require changes between both HK2 and Jersey.  HK2 allowed some bad usages of one of its API which has since been explicitly checked for and disallowed.  However Jersey uses the API in that way, which means that Jersey will have to change to do something else.  That has not happened yet but will.

Comment: Just saw this comment. Thanks for looking into this we'll keep on using 2.8 in the mean time. Do you know what jersey release is being targeted for the changes? If not we'll just check the release notes periodically and look for the updates.

Comment: I'll ask the jersey guys